# Highest voted tag questions vs popular questions of the day

Tags: discussion, new-nav

Personally I use 3 different 'views':

- New in tag/overall
- Popular today (or hot/week in the old navigation)
- Most votes in tag

Switching to whatever view I wanted used to take a single click, right now switching to any view except 'new' takes at least 4 clicks (open date range menu, pick date range, etc.) and at most 5 clicks. I realize that this might not be the most typical usage (I used to answer a lot more questions, but right now I am visiting SE primarily as a 'fun' site to read), but it should be possible to make it at least more efficient than this.

Comment: @RobertCartaino: Shouldn't this be [tag:discussion] as well, because I am not offering a specific proposal/[tag:feature-request], but instead I am pointing out a specific 'pain point' (not sure that's an english expression) and asking more or less for ideas (the discussion part) on how it could be improved (the feature request part).

Comment: Unless you're suggesting a specific solution, it's not really a [feature-request] at all. But to answer your question, the required tags are designed to be a pick-one selection. A feature-request is inherently open to discussion by design (as are bugs and support, I guess), so the extra tag is redundant.

Comment: @RobertCartaino Well, as I am asking for a new feature (rather than, say, just how we should handle a certain situation) I thought it made sense to tag both. Regardless, perfectly fine with just [tag:discussion], but the other way round didn't seem to make a lot of sense. But either way, with all due respect for your moderatorship, your claim about it being a 'pick-one' selection has to be... somewhat personal?, because the picking dialog states explicitly "At least one of these tags is required" and more than 5000 questions have more than 1 of those 4 tags.